# Make python id particular length by trimming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, trim

I have id column in a dataframe with index type object:

`df=pd.DataFrame({'id':['zxcv1234','yz0123','a8791']}, dtype=object)`

I want to get only the four characters from the left. So, the resulting ids would be 1234,0123 and 8791.

How to do this ?

Comment: `df['id'].str[:4]`

Comment: This gives the first four character.

Comment: sorry, misread the question. Try this `df['id'].str[-4:]`